# why isn't the styling on the line break working?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I was doing a challenge on frontendmentor.io and I'm currently stuck on one thing: the styling on a line-break isn't being applied.

I've made a pen on codepen for ease : [codepen link](https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100)

Html code:

```
    <main>
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img" src="./images/image-equilibrium.jpg" alt="blueish-red equilibrium cube">
            <div class="card-content">
                <h2 class="card-title">Equilibrium #3429</h2>
                <p>Our Equilibrium collection promotes balance and calm.</p>
                <div class="row card-icons">
                    <div class="eth row"><img class="eth-icon" alt="ethereum value to purchase item" src="./images/icon-ethereum.svg"><h3 class="icon-text">0.041eth</h3></div>
                    <div class="days-left row"><img class="clock-icon" alt="days-remaining icon" src="./images/icon-clock.svg"><h3 class="icon-text"> 3 days left</h3></div>
                </div>
                <hr class="line-break">
                <div class="creator row">
                    <img class="creator-pfp" src="./images/image-avatar.png" alt="Creator profile picture">
                    <p>Creation of <strong>Jules Wyvern</strong></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

css :

```
/*   typography and styling   */
h2 {
    color: var(--title-color);
    font-family: var(--title-font);
    font-size: 1.75rem;
}

p {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.eth .icon-text {
    color: var(--text-color-eth);
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.days-left .icon-text {
    color: var(--text-color);
    font-family: var(--body-font);
    font-weight: 300;
}

hr.line-break {
    border-top: 1px solid #aaaaea);
}
```

Comment: you have a typo `border-top: 1px solid #aaaaea);` should be `border-top: 1px solid #aaaaea;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the styles for line break.
I Noticed that you have added ")" at the end. you have to remove it.

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPe3Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is your code:

```
hr.line-break {
    border-top: 1px solid #aaaaea;
}
```

Delete the **)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `hr`  take in any style.

You can use an empty
`<div class='line-break'></div>`
instead

Like this

```
.line-break{
 width:100vw;
 hight:1px;
 border-top: 1px solid #aaaaea;
}
```

Comment: hr can be restyled and even genertaes pseudo-elements ;)  example : https://jsfiddle.net/6m5wd7a0/